# Windows Phone Linq2Twitter - Getting an authorized user's screen name, id, and name?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-twitter

I'm a noob in LinQ and having troubles with Linq2Twitter and Twitter API in general.

I cannot understand how to get an authorized user's screen name, id, and name after a successful authorization.

I searched discussion threads online and the only advice I got from Joe was to use async call when querying for results. Except that I don't have the MaterializedAsyncCallback for some reason so I'm using AsyncCallback instead.

Here are the steps that I take all the way from authorizing to attempting to obtain the user's info:

1. Create a PinAuthorizer with my consumer key and secret as credentials

   ```
   this.pinAuth = new PinAuthorizer
   {
       Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
        {
            ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY,
            ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET
        },
        UseCompression = true,
        GoToTwitterAuthorization = pageLink =>
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
            WebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(pageLink + "&force_login=true", UriKind.Absolute));
        })
    };
   ```
2. Authorize Begin

   ```
   this.pinAuth.BeginAuthorize(resp => ...
   ```
3. Enter the pin and thus getting access token and secret in pinAuth.OAuthTwitter:

   ```
   pinAuth.CompleteAuthorize(
       this.pin,
       completeResp => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
       { ...
   ```
4. Then, I try to get the user ... with an async call as that's what Joe Mayo recommended in other threads.

   ```
   ITwitterAuthorizer auth = pinAuth;
   TwitterContext twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(pinAuth);
   (from user in twitterCtx.User
    where user.UserID != "JoeMayo"
    select user).AsyncCallback(asyncResponse => {
        var response = asyncResponse.ToList();
        User acc = response.FirstOrDefault();
    // Anything in this block is pointless
    // as I never get into this async callback block.
    // But this is where I expect to get the user's info
    // (screen name, name, id, etc.)
   });
   ```

I never get the async response.
(I also do not have `MaterializedAsyncCallback`  for some reason).

How do I get the authorized user's screen name, id, and name?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually fire the query at all!

```
(from user in twitterCtx.User
 where user.UserID != "JoeMayo"
 select user).AsyncCallback(users => {
    // result is in users variable
    var user = users.SingleOrDefault();
    if(user != null)
    {
        // use user here.
    }
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: answer is what you need. More info on same question here: http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/discussions/437277